# Clickonce application wont install

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, clickonce

I am having winform application which is deployed with `ClickOnce` publisher.

I publish my application to local PC, then transfer files (setup, manifest and version folder from Application Files folder inside) to my Windows Server 2003 and then there I start setup.

I have deployed 168 versions of it and it worked normally but today it stopped working.

What I mean by that is when I start `SETUP` it just starts it and nothing happens.

I have started TASK MANAGER and inside It I see `MyApplicationName.exe` starts but also what I see is `Dw20.exe` (if it is important).

I have tried publishing another time (new version) but same happens.

Since it is not starting from `setup` file I went to `Application Files/1_0_0_X` and started manifest file from there and then error window appears which says:

`Application download didn't succeed....`

and in `Details..` I have this log:

```
    PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 5.2.3790.131072 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.1
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Program%20Files/Magacin/Application%20Files/Magacin_1_0_0_170/Magacin.application
    Deployment Provider url     : http://desktop-i40i5hu/Magacin/Magacin.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Program Files\Magacin\Application Files\Magacin_1_0_0_170\Magacin.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://desktop-i40i5hu/Magacin/Magacin.application did not succeed.
        + The remote name could not be resolved: 'desktop-i40i5hu'

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [20.09.2018 15:20:10] : Activation of C:\Program Files\Magacin\Application Files\Magacin_1_0_0_170\Magacin.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [20.09.2018 15:20:13] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://desktop-i40i5hu/Magacin/Magacin.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The remote name could not be resolved: 'desktop-i40i5hu'
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Since I saw this message `The remote name could not be resolved: 'desktop-i40i5hu'` I went to check which PC is `desktop-i40i5hu` and I came up that it is my local pc (One that I am developing app in) so I thought that is problem BUT when I went to manifest file from 30 versions ago, it has same configuration and it is also mentioned this pc name and it worked normally.

What could possibly be the problem here?

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
  <assemblyIdentity name="Magacin.application" version="1.0.0.171" publicKeyToken="7c841f97b6f4e6dd" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <description asmv2:publisher="Magacin" asmv2:product="Magacin" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <deployment install="true" mapFileExtensions="true">
    <deploymentProvider codebase="http://desktop-i40i5hu/Magacin/Magacin.application" />
  </deployment>
  <compatibleFrameworks xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
    <framework targetVersion="4.0" profile="Full" supportedRuntime="4.0.30319" />
  </compatibleFrameworks>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="Application Files\Magacin_1_0_0_171\Magacin.exe.manifest" size="17270">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Magacin.exe" version="1.0.0.171" publicKeyToken="7c841f97b6f4e6dd" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" type="win32" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>rAGYfZ9qSVQRPuG5wA0Z5LpiXiw=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
<publisherIdentity name="CN=DESKTOP-1VBU9II\arist" issuerKeyHash="fe4200ba8b6dbe28648e23c775f06fa5ae24f327" /><Signature Id="StrongNameSignature" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>2qtxvGAyieS+/aFm11SpiFuvfB8=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>EEW8FQAdOEK8gnSfzfwKxbbEUpRxF2bQ1g0zAQZqfzUNHYYbYfFuuJSaQG/H0/eQrwTm+ZkTgbzHaEQ9Ws/nHH+HnXRLP8JaL3VQKfZJCgqZgR4by2y/ShqWR529f+QkuHFgWgZa5HbJoqg0Qbudn+tBltHIFgDGQfGHMVFWiEo=</SignatureValue><KeyInfo Id="StrongNameKeyInfo"><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>1UHNMvkLBxDsocHDOsb0/lpgXi0zrit5zD9an7vz5uuwDbG4n6j0BBJVi6oaUHBEB1QxL4DfirBbeJUpE5+pmswg/ybnFjD2l2VE93J6IMyyAiWx5RqNfrf0e0IuaspmgMoEi2MScmHKu+H5We0ECBhMyB6S+JvVvF4LFBgFcEk=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue><msrel:RelData xmlns:msrel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/rel/2005/reldata"><r:license xmlns:r="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:as="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pki/2005/Authenticode"><r:grant><as:ManifestInformation Hash="1f7caf5b88a954d766a1fdbee4893260bc71abda" Description="" Url=""><as:assemblyIdentity name="Magacin.application" version="1.0.0.171" publicKeyToken="7c841f97b6f4e6dd" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" /></as:ManifestInformation><as:SignedBy /><as:AuthenticodePublisher><as:X509SubjectName>CN=DESKTOP-1VBU9II\arist</as:X509SubjectName></as:AuthenticodePublisher></r:grant><r:issuer><Signature Id="AuthenticodeSignature" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>B+tpk5gCS54I1V73fzPct5OPdDU=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>gRIzJFslS3kwWhE2ttwVhI6Sp6GZpQ18GaVXlk8P8fcLsnPfUWkIG+hUZ2/bEhaXHa54n6+Eloaqf5we64r0zvqL+k6DGZp+u6kXVGmoVN7myvLC+9RER+KvDhaGoCqQRZakGsQALzH9R8Abb3wavGVqiY+GWdWwtBTyY37jCpc=</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>1UHNMvkLBxDsocHDOsb0/lpgXi0zrit5zD9an7vz5uuwDbG4n6j0BBJVi6oaUHBEB1QxL4DfirBbeJUpE5+pmswg/ybnFjD2l2VE93J6IMyyAiWx5RqNfrf0e0IuaspmgMoEi2MScmHKu+H5We0ECBhMyB6S+JvVvF4LFBgFcEk=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue><X509Data><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></r:issuer></r:license></msrel:RelData></KeyInfo></Signature></asmv1:assembly>
```

Looks like problem isn't this.

I have commented sections of my code to see where is it making problem and came up that this started making problem:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

I do not know why but I will as other question for this.

Comment: It also says _"Downloading http://desktop-i40i5hu/Magacin/Magacin.application did not succeed"_! Have you done a diff on the old and new manifest files?

Comment: No. Everything is same expect version difference. Problem is now that even old manifest files are not working if I start them.

Comment: It's been a very very long time since I used ClickOnce. Isn't there a file you can edit to correct the download location?

Comment: Not sure. I will post up my manifest file in 2 minutes so if you could look at it it would be awesome. I tried changing something but not worked.

Comment: Can you change the line `<deploymentProvider codebase="http://desktop-i40i5hu/Magacin/Magacin.application" />` to point to the correct path on the server?

Comment: I am so sorry I haven't mentioned in comment I edited post and found out the problem and it is not related to ClickOnce. Thank you so much.

Comment: Good that you found it!

Comment: Whole day testing code for that and now I cannot find solution to other thing since no documentation for it (or I cannot find it) so I hope when I post another question someone know solution :)